# Regular expression to validate US and Canada zipcodes - Runtime Error 438 excel

Tags: regex, excel, vba, zipcode

I have written this code to help with validating the zip code cells in our supplier form. I am wanting it to validate when the move on to the next cell. I am getting run-time 438 error: object doesn't support this property or method when I try and move on to the next cell. I need this to validate all US and Canada zip codes (english is being used).

I've tried doing this with data validation and I can either have the US or Canada but not both.

```vb
Private Sub worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        'Erm, nothing to do here....
    ElseIf Not Intersect(target, Range("B39,B50")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim searchRange     As Excel.Range
    Dim cell            As Variant
    Dim RegEx           As Object

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With RegEx
        .Pattern = "^(\d{5}(-\d{4})?|[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTVXY]\d[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z] ?\d[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]\d)$"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
    End With

    Set searchRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B39,B50")
    For Each cell In searchRange.Cells
       If RegEx.IsMatch(subjectString, "^(\d{5}(-\d{4})?|[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTVXY]\d[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z] ?\d[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]\d)$") Then
            MsgBox ("Valid ZIP code")
        Else
            MsgBox ("Invalid ZIP code")
        End If
    Next cell
    Set searchRange = Nothing
    Set RegEx = Nothing

End Sub
```

The debug line is

```vb
  If RegEx.IsMatch(subjectString, "^(\d{5}(-\d{4})?|[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTVXY]\d[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z] ?\d[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]\d)$") Then
```

I don't care if I use data validation or VBA I just need something to be in place to validate this. Please be detailed in your responses I'm still fairly "green" with VBA and Regex.

Comment: That indenting hurts my brain :-(

Comment: Where is declared `subjectString` ? It holds no value, hence nothing to match... i guess that's why you are getting the error. Using [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) helps a lot.

Comment: I might be wrong on this, as I prefer to use `Like` operator in vba and string functions instead, so I'm not so familiar with regex, but I was unable to find any reference to `IsMatch` method in VBA in the official documentation. I only found `IsMatch` in the /dotnet/ documentation, which while it shares similarities is not the same as VBA

Comment: @Rawrplus i`m not big fan of RegEx either, but looks like you are right... [Microsoft Beefs Up VBScript with Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974570(v=msdn.10))

Comment: So, I used this [link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s14.html) and it didn't call out the subjectstring. 

I will gladly take another way to write this not using a Regex, I just haven't been able to find anything out there to do both at the same time in the same cell. I'm not sure on the `Option explicit` comment.

Comment: Emily, **Always** put `Option Explicit` at the top of modules. Always. For the novice, the effect is picking up typing errors and ensuring that all variables are declared to help avoid the types of errors you see here. In addition, with `Option Explicit` on, the VB engine provides better debugging messages.

Comment: I have this running on the worksheet tab does it need to run under module 1?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/175616/fix-error-438-object-doesn-t-support-this-property-or-method

Comment: This is great feedback but there's not a solid solution yet.

Comment: Do you only want to look at cells B39 and B50 (which is what `Range("B39,B50")` produces - a multiple-area range where each of those two cells is in a separate area) or did you want to look at all the cells B39, B40 ... B49, B50  - which would be `Range("B39:B50")` ?

Comment: Yes I just need it to look at those two cells.

Answer (score 0):

Should work (assuming the pattern is OK):

```
Private Sub worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal target As Range)

    Static RegEx As Object '<<
    Dim searchRange As Range

    Set searchRange = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B39, B50"))
    If searchRange Is Nothing then Exit Sub

    'see if we need to set up the regexp object
    If RegEx Is Nothing Then
        Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With RegEx
            .Pattern = "^(\d{5}(-\d{4})?|[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTVXY]\d" & _
                       "[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z] ?\d[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]\d)$"
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
        End With
    End If

    For Each cell In searchRange.Cells
        MsgBox IIf(RegEx.Test(cell.Value), "Valid", "Invalid") & " ZIP code"
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Edit: if you have two things you want to do in Worksheet_Change then you can either combine all of your code inside the one event handler, or do something like this:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    HandleFirstThing Target
    DoSomethingElse Target
End Sub

Sub HandleFirstThing(Target As Range)
   'first thing to handle
End Sub

Sub DoSomethingElse(Target As Range)
   'next thing to handle
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok so this is kind of working, it is throwing up the message box when i select the cell and not when i move on from the cell

Comment: `Selection_change` triggers on selecting a new cell/range: maybe the event you need is `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: anyway to do this without getting an Ambiguous name if i already have something defined as worksheet_change ?

Comment: There's no reason you can't combine those two into a single procedure.

Comment: I love that you're giving me another challenge.. I presume that if i have problems debugging this that I'll have to submit another post? haha 

or is it as easy as doing `Exit Sub` then running the second code and then `end sub`

Comment: This is dropping off the leading 00's in zip codes. Any suggestion?

Comment: The code doesn't change the cell content or format, so can you expand a little on exactly what's happening? (maybe along with one or two sample values)

Comment: when you enter in "08904" or "07208" the first zero will drop off and then message box will prompt as a "invalid zip code".

Comment: Did you format those cells as Text? Otherwise, Excel strips leading zeros from numeric values.